# Plot histogram from two columns of csv using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, matplotlib, histogram

I have a csv file containing two columns. What I'd like to do is to plot a histogram based on these two columns.

My code is as follows:

```
data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
```

My csv data is made like this:

```
Age     Blood Pressure
51           120
..           ...
```

I tried with `plt.hist(data['Age'], bins=10)` which only gives me an histogram based on the first column and its frequency, the same goes for the second column.
Is there a way to plot an histogram which shows me "Ages" in the x-Axis and "Blood Pressure" in the y-Axis?

Comment: What you are describing is, by definition, not a histogram. Is there a reason why you don't want to use a scatter plot to plot the two variables?

Answer (score 2):

If it actually makes sense for you, you can change the `orientation` of the second plot:

```py
plt.hist(data['Age'], bins=10, alpha=.5)
plt.hist(data['Blood Pressure'], bins=10, alpha=.5, orientation='horizontal')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(data['Age'], data['Blood Pressure'])
```